# Quick documentation popup had been replaced by platform window

Tags: intellij-idea, popup, intellij-14

After 14.1.4->14.1.5 update on *IntelliJ Idea* I had been faced with an annoying UI feature. When I press quick-doc shortcut (Ctrl+Q for my keymap) a platform specific window appears instead of lightweight popup window. In other worlds I have just floating *Tool window* (a right panel button had been activated).

[image: Platform window instead of popup]

My question is how to return plain old popup *documentation window* with no window title bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just click the red cross button and the window should be restored back to a pop-up.

Or just hit <kbd>F1</kbd> (OS X) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (Windows, Linux).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I found it was a Java or Linux issue. Once I had pushed Ctrl+Q there is no popup appears, and after second one a _Toolbar window_ had been acivated. I.e. there is some render problem on my PC (linux rulez)

Comment: Thank you, I was getting mad